# How to read data from embedded database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-resource, jet

I wanna improve one application which database is unknown for me. So i have interface to work with but no data to fill forms/documents etc in a new application... Installation folder only containts `.dll` files without any clue of database. For now i have tried to inspect `.dll` files with [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) and found only source code of those dll's without any "physical" location of database on my hard drive so i started to think it's embedded in application. I also inspected all my hard drive to try find it in some hidden folder without success. After further investigation i figured out that i have to get Microsoft Access database who works with **Jet Oledb 4.0.**. I found this line of code where it says :

```
this._connectionString = "PROVIDER=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; Data Source=" + this.DataBasePath + "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = 12345678";
```

So basically i know the password of that database but i don't know where is that database. And now i am stuck because i have never worked with embedded database. I only got installed application and installation file (which was generated thru visual studio).

Is it possible to get tables/data from embedded database and if so how to do it? Is it maybe possible to get database from installation file and if so how to do it?

Any help would be nice.

Thanks KuKeC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong there has to be an actual file to store the database so why dont you just look for a *.db file in your system and open it with a db tool to check the content

Comment: I searched it and found some databases but none of them is from my application. I also tried to change some values of tables into application and then search whole disk with parameter "modified" today and still nothing.

Comment: I've honestly never heard of an embedded database without files and since no one seems to be correcting me, I say widen your search: `*.db OR *.ACCDB OR *.NSF OR *.FP7 OR *.ACCDC OR *.FDB OR *.PDB` There's just too many to go through all of them without any hint on the architecture, but you can still try to add more and filter through the latest.